# Sending e-mail CDO

Tags: vba, excel, cdo.message

I am trying to send a PDF and an Excel spreadsheet page using CDO.
I have it for most ISP but I cannot make it work for gmail.

I have an account and it works once in a while when I try it (go figure). I also, have a friend with a gmail account and I cannot get it to work ...ever with his account.

I have worked on this for 3 solid days and I give up.
It will take someone much better that I to get it done.
Below is the code I have tried without success .

Please help.

```
  Sub SEND_PDF_SHEET_WITH_CDO()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler3:

Dim filepath As String

filepath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name   & ".pdf" 'TODO:change filepath for the temp pdf file

    Range("A5:P31").Select

    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        filepath, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields

    With Flds

    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = smtp.gmail.com
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25   ' I have tried 25, 465, 587 and more
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "MyEmail"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = MyPassword
    .Update
    End With

    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .From = "MyEmail" & "<NCAA@something.nl>" 'TODO:change email address here
        .To = "MyEmail"
        .Subject = "Hello"
        .HTMLBody = Range("A350").Value
        .AddAttachment (filepath)
        .Send
    End With

    Set iMsg = Nothing
    Set iConf = Nothing
    Kill filepath

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler3:

MsgBox "YOUR   PDF   E-MAIL DID NOT GO THROUGH.  IT MAY BE YOU" _
& Chr$(13) _
& Chr$(13) _
& "HAVE NOT COMPLETED YOUR NON-OULOOK E-MAIL QUESTIONS" _
& Chr$(13) _
& Chr$(13) _
& "OR ENTERED THE INFORMATION INCORRECTLY." _
& Chr$(13) _
& Chr$(13) _
& "PLEASE TRY AGAIN AFTER RE-ENTERING YOUR INFORMATION."
Range("B8").Select
STOP_SUB = "YES"

    Set iMsg = Nothing
    Set iConf = Nothing
     Kill filepath

Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub SEND_EXCEL_SHEET_WITH_CDO()

 On Error GoTo ErrHandler2:

'Working in 97-2007
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
        Dim Flds As Variant

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007
            'We exit the sub when your answer is NO in the security dialog that you only
            'see  when you copy a sheet from a xlsm file with macro's disabled.
            If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
                With Application
                    .ScreenUpdating = True
                    .EnableEvents = True
                End With
                MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
                Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                Case 52:
                    If .HasVBProject Then
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                    Else
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                    End If
                Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
                Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    End With

    'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Part of " & Sourcewb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields
    With Flds

    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = Range("JA1").Value
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = Range("JA2").Value
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = Range("JA3").Value
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = Range("JA4").Value
    .Update
    End With

    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = "MyEmail"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .From = "My Name" & "<NCAA@something.nl>"
        .Subject = "HELLO"
        .TextBody = "HELLO AGAIN" '<-- email body
        .AddAttachment TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
        .Send
    End With

    'Delete the file you have send
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

Exit Sub
ErrHandler2:

MsgBox "YOUR    EXCEL    E-MAIL DID NOT GO THROUGH.  IT MAY BE YOU" _
& Chr$(13) _
& Chr$(13) _
& "HAVE NOT COMPLETED YOUR NON-OULOOK E-MAIL QUESTIONS" _
& Chr$(13) _
& Chr$(13) _
& "OR ENTERED THE INFORMATION INCORRECTLY." _
& Chr$(13) _
& Chr$(13) _
& "PLEASE TRY AGAIN AFTER RE-ENTERING YOUR INFORMATION."
Range("B8").Select
STOP_SUB = "YES"
Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I think `smtp.gmail.com` should be in the form of string like `"smtp.gmail.com"`. Does it make a difference if you change it to that?

Comment: Maybe this is just a code redacting typo but smtp.gmail.com probably doesn't like email from @something.nl being forwarded through it.

Comment: Jeeped is right, that too. If you use Ron de Bruin's code, make sure you read and understand the comments he wrote together with it. And try it first using simple examples.

Answer (score 2):

This code works. **PLUS** it displays any errors which tell you why it didn't work.

```
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
emailObj.From     = "dc@gmail.com"

emailObj.To       = "dc@gmail.com"

emailObj.Subject  = "Test CDO"
emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO"

emailObj.AddAttachment "C:/Users/User/Desktop/err.fff"

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration

emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "dc"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "Ss"
emailConfig.Fields.Update

On Error Resume Next
emailObj.Send

If err.number = 0 then 
    Msgbox "Done"
Else
    Msgbox err.number & " " & err.description
    err.clear
End If
```

Also your account at www.gmail.com needs to be set to allow SMTP access.

The configuration info comes from Outlook Express (last in WinXP, renamed to Windows Mail in Vista, and dropped from Win7 and later). This shows default configuration on your computer.

```
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration

On Error Resume Next    

For Each fld in emailConfig.Fields
msgbox fld.name & " = " & fld
Next
```

Also CDO for Windows 2000 is not always included in all editions/versions of windows. See http://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/171440

Comment: 1.  smtp.gmail.com is a typo I used "smtp.gmail.com"

2. The From address was not  @something.nl   it was actually my email address.
I did not want to enter my e-mail and password.

3. This is Ron de Bruin's code and if I run it like he writes it works perfectly. It will send ONLY a text message that I enter. 
I want to send part of an excel spreadsheet as BOTH a spreadsheet and a PDF.

What do you mean by "Your account at www.gmail.com needs to be set to allow SMTP access." and how do I do that.