# Sending an Email from Excel when Outlook not available using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, remote-access

I want to send stakeholders an e-mail when a subordinate makes any updates in the Excel worksheet. I hope to use a `Workbook_BeforeSave` event where an e-mail is triggered from the subordinate's Outlook account.

The subordinate/user needs Outlook configured/installed in their system. If not mail wont be triggered.

Is there any way to overcome this, like sending the mail triggering request to a remote computer/server where Outlook is preconfigured and sending the mail from that computer/server to the stakeholder using a common or centralized Email id?

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objOutlookRecip As Recipient
    Dim Recipients As Recipients

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Set Recipients = objOutlookMsg.Recipients
    Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients.Add("receiver@domain.com")
    objOutlookRecip.Type = 1

    objOutlookMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = "sender@domain.com"
    objOutlookMsg.Subject = "Testing this macro"
    objOutlookMsg.HTMLBody = "Testing this macro "

    For Each objOutlookRecip In objOutlookMsg.Recipients
        objOutlookRecip.Resolve
    Next

    objOutlookMsg.Display
    objOutlookMsg.Send

    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043416/sending-e-mail-cdo/29043896#29043896

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sendmail and https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/div/mail4.htm

Answer (score -1):

```
Option Explicit
```

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

```
' SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
Dim objOutlook As Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
Dim objEmail As Object
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objEmail
    .to = "webadmin@encodedna.com"
    .Subject = "This is a test message from Arun Banik"
    .Body = "Hi there"
    .Display        ' DISPLAY MESSAGE.
End With

' CLEAR.
Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

ErrHandler:
'
End Sub

All you need to do is change the .Display property with .Send property.

```
With objEmail
    .to = "arunbanik21@rediffmail.com"
    .Subject = "This is a test message from Arun"
    .Body = "Hi there"
    .Send       ' SEND THE MESSAGE.
End With
```

For more please check here, https://www.encodedna.com/excel/send-email-from-excel-using-vba-and-outlook.htm

Comment: thank you. But your code only works when the outlook is pre configured. It won't work if the Outlook is not configured/installed.

Comment: Then please give it a try as mentioned in this article, 

https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-send-email-from-excel/

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps,

1. We need to send emails from Outlook. Since Outlook is an outside object first thing we need to do is to set the object reference to “Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library”.
2. In VBA, Go to Tools > References.
3. Now we will see the object reference library. In this window, we need to set the reference to “Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library.”
4. After setting the object reference, click on, Ok.
5. Now we can access Outlook object in VBA coding

```
Sub SendEmail_Example1()
    Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application 'To refer to outlook application
    Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application 'To launch outlook application
    Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem 'To refer new outlook email
    Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'To launch new outlook 
    email
    EmailItem.To = "Hi@gmail.com"
    EmailItem.CC = "hello@gmail.com"
    EmailItem.Subject = "Test Email From Excel VBA"
EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hi," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This is my first email from Excel" & _
                    vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Regards," & vbNewLine & _
                    "VBA Coder" 'VbNewLine is the VBA Constant to insert a new line
    EmailItem.Send
End Sub
```

For more, can you please give a try as mentioned in this article,

https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-send-email-from-excel/

Comment: The Outlook application is not installed on the user's computer.

Comment: I actually want to send the email notification from a remote system with common mail id to the stake holders